# share Linkedin API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am working on LinkedIn share API, but I'm facing some problems.

My code:

```
public function shareAPI()
{
    $datatopost ="<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?><share><comment>hi</comment><content><title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title><submitted-url>http://google.com</submitted-url><submitted-image-url></submitted-image-url></content>
    <visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";
    $this->_oauth_token_secret=$_SESSION[_oauth_token_secret];
    $this->_oauth->fetch(BASE_API_URL.'/v1/people/~/shares',$datatopost,OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT);

}
```

When this function is called, it doesn't send the message to the wall.
Please help.

Comment: Did you get to fix it ? I would be intrested

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific? What is the problem?
One suggestion would be to just use this code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=80&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```